# How to add a WHERE clause conditionally without using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to add a clause conditionally in the WHERE portion of a stored procedure but I understand that using CASE is really bad.  Here's essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
@StartDate
@EndDate
@ClientID
SELECT field_1, field_2, datefield_3 
from tblTable
Where datefield_3 Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
 --If @ClientID > 0 then add
AND field_1 = @ClientID
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are very many cases when `case` is the best (and fastest) tool to use.  This case might not be one of them, but don't rule out `case` without testing to see how it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as:

```
@StartDate
@EndDate
@ClientID
SELECT field_1, field_2, datefield_3 
from tblTable
Where datefield_3 Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND (@ClientID <= 0 OR field_1 = @ClientID)
```

If @ClientID <= 0, the additional condition isn't evaluated. I.e. if @ClientID > 0, `field_1 = @ClientID` is evaluated!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

```
...
Where datefield_3 Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND (field_1 > 0 OR field_1 = @ClientID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@StartDate
@EndDate
@ClientID


IF ClientID>0
BEGIN
SELECT field_1, field_2, datefield_3 
from tblTable
Where datefield_3 Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND field_1 = @ClientID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT field_1, field_2, datefield_3 
from tblTable
Where datefield_3 Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
END
```